# Add a label to a stencil shape of type basic.Image in jointjs-Rappid

Tags: json, label, jointjs, rappid

I have a stencil shape of type **basic.Image** which is showed in Stencil without a label as in the following screenshot:

[image]

Is there any way I can add a label which will be displayed **at the bottom of this shape in the Stencil**?

The full code is the following:

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Image({
    attrs: {
        image: { width: 50, height: 50, 'xlink:href': 'data:image/png;base64,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' },
        text: { text: 'image', 'font-size': 9, display: '', stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Rappid/ jointJS support, I solved my problem by disabling a CSS rule which was responsible for hiding the label of any Stencil shape of type basic.Image this way:

```
.stencil .elements .element.basic.Image text
```

This label is now visible under this shape at Stencil and it is disappeared when adding this shape to the graph, as wanted.